# RoR PUT with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, post, put

I've a Rails server and I'm trying to make a PUT using the $.ajax function. The server gives a POST 200 OK but the DB data it's not being updated.

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
        url: this.SERVER_IP+ "/user_coordinates/" + this.FRIEND_ID,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: {_method:'PUT',
               page: {"user_coordinate":
                        {"meetinglat":this.meetingPoint.getPosition().lat(),
                         "meetinglong":this.meetingPoint.getPosition().lng()}
                     }
              },
        success: function(msg){
                   console.log("Sucess! Object: ");
                   console.log(msg);
                 },
        error: function(msg){
                 console.log("Error! Object: ");
                 console.log(msg);
               }
        });
```

The error function is being called. What could be the problem here?

Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: It could be anything; we can't see your logs, so it's difficult to help.

Comment: What do you see in the server console? Have you tried to add ".json" to the url string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've the found the problem. Using logger.debug in my controller i've noticed that it was expecting params[:user_coordinate] and in my ajax call I was passing something like:

```
data: {_method:'PUT',
               page: {"user_coordinate":
                        {"meetinglat":this.meetingPoint.getPosition().lat(),
                         "meetinglong":this.meetingPoint.getPosition().lng()}
                     }
              }
```

instead of:

```
data: {_method:'PUT',
               user_coordinate: {"meetinglat":this.meetingPoint.getPosition().lat(),
                         "meetinglong":this.meetingPoint.getPosition().lng()}
      },
```

Now it's working! ;)

logger.debug "params #{params[:user_coordinate]}"

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Rails controller that is the receiving end, in your case user_coordinates_controller, try to print out what the parameters are,
--> puts params.inspect

Another note, it looks like you have type POST on your AJAX call